# Prevent software to log out by interacting

Tags: windows-10, automation

I have some softwares that will log me out if I don't interact with them for a given amount of time (as a security option).

However I don't want that to happen so I'm trying to find a way to automatically interact with them every 10 mins for example.

How can I do that? Possibly in background.

Answer (score 0):

[AutoHotKey](http://AutoHotkey.com) again.

Here's a detailed [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/97998/how-to-make-your-computer-press-a-key-every-x-seconds/) on how to get a key press on a set time. This can be modified to other buttons, or mice movement if need be.